# No such file in the directory, but the file exists for Mac

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

I am trying to find the folder using the terminal, however, it can't seems to find the folder tho, the folder actually exists. I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of the folder]

Comment: What happens when you do `cd data-w*`? If that succeeds, do `pwd` to determine the actual directory name you are in.

Comment: Btw., please add the tags 'mac' (or 'macos'?) and 'bash' to the tags.

Comment: And if and when `cd data-w*` succeeds, do `echo "[$PWD]"` to see the actual directory name you are in. It could be there is trailing whitespace in the name.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked, but I still can't really know the problem. or is it just that its a trailing space I can see?

Comment: If you did `echo "[$PWD]"`, you would probably see a space on the left of the`]`. So maybe something like `[data-wrangling ]`.